# Django get reverse url into a variable

Tags: python, django

I want a reverse url into a variable. I have to apps. one account and another profiles.

my main url

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',      
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls', namespace="account")), 
    url(r'^profiles/', include('profiles.urls', namespace="profiles")),
)
```

my profiles app url

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^view/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.profile, name="profile"),
)
```

my account app url

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^message/add_new/$', views.new_message, name='new_message'),

)
```

my account app view

```
def new_message(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        sender_username = request.user.username
        sender_url = reverse('prfiles.views.profile', args=(sender_username,))
```

but I got '`NoReverseMatch at`' error. Please suggest me a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, `prfiles.views.profile` seems like typo.

Fix typo (if it is) or use the URL pattern name instead of the view name.

```
sender_url = reverse('profiles:profile', args=(sender_username,))
```

See [Reversing namespaced URLs | Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls).

Comment: my view in account app. but my url in profiles app. how can I connect this. Is anything want to import?

Comment: @SAFEERN, Did you try replacing `prfiles.views.profile` with `profile` as I suggest in the answer ?

Comment: yes. but I got NoReverseMatch at /account/message/add_new/
Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '(u'safeer',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: @SAFEERN, What about `sender_url = reverse('profile', kwargs={'username': sender_username})` ?

Comment: got same error. NoReverseMatch at /account/message/add_new/
Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'username': u'safeer'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [] . I want this url 192.168.1.22:8000/profiles/view/safeer/

Comment: @SAFEERN, Ah, you used namesapce! use `profiles:profile` instead of `profile`.

Comment: yes. got. Thank you very much. what is the method to get absolute url?

Comment: @SAFEERN, from request object ?

Comment: @SAFEERN, I don't know. Please post another question.

Comment: @SAFEERN, Try `urlparse.urljoin(request.build_absolute_uri(), reverse('...'))`.